# Store ArrayList in Cookies & get cookies values in Listbox when pageLoads

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, arraylist, listbox

I am working on Ecommerce website. Here I want to add products in cart which stores productsID in arraylist & this arrayList gets saved in cookies. Now I want to get the ProductID stored in cookies in ListBox when cart page gets loads..

I have used following code to get added items in cart

```
List<int> ids = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("ItemInCart") != null ? (List<int>)HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("ItemInCart") : null;
if (ids != null) {
    foreach (int id in ids) {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("select * from customer where id={0}", id));
    }
}
```

Error

> BC30311: Value of type 'System.Web.HttpCookie' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if (Request.Cookies["ItemInCart"] != null)
        {
          List<int> myList = Request.Cookies["ItemInCart"].Value.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();            
        }
```

Then add it to the ListBox,

```
if (myList != null) {
    foreach (int id in myList) {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("select * from customer where id={0}", id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Input String was not in a correct form on this Line.  List<int> myList = Request.Cookies["ItemInCart"].Value.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();

Comment: I think the cookies are stored as a list<string>

Comment: Try this,  List<string> yourList = Request.Cookies["ItemInCart"].Value.Split(',').Select(x => x).ToList();

Comment: Can you suggest I am doing it right or not? If Items added to cart then it will stored added product ID in arrayList & arraylist will be stored in cookies. If user visit cart page then I want to populate Listview from the that cookies. Is my logic correct?